# One of two EditText field not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, android-edittext

I am making an android dialog box, with the following XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Enter Name" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:hint="Enter E-Mail" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/addIt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

However, when I launch and run it,
the `EditText` with id `name` is showing up but the one with id `email` is not showing up.

Also, on the **Design* section of the considered XML it shows the error
`Paint.setShadowLayer is not supported`

and also, when I run it, I also get the error in log as :

`SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length`

could anyone tell me what the issue seems to be and how I can fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK fixed it!

In the EditText with ID `email`

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"`

had to be changed to

`android:layout_width="match_parent"`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:background="#FFFFFF">


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/nameLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:hint="Enter Name" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/emailLayout"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nameLayout">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:hint="Enter E-Mail" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/addIt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In `RelativeLayout`, we have define the positions of the children.

For example,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 2"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnButton1"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnButton3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 3"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btnButton1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here, **Button2** will be placed on the right of **Button1** and **Button3** is placed below **Button1**.

In your case, the `name` and `email` are overlapping with each other because no position was defined properly.